# jquery ajax submithandler function does not work

Tags: jquery

Somehow my code for the ajax submithandler does not work. I want to have the form (myForm) being submitted by the user only when jquery validate() validates the form correctly.

Form validation works ok, but submitting the form does not create the proper response and seems to reload the webpage.

I checked at http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api and http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ but cant figure out the fault in my submit handler code.

Please your help.

Code:

```
<script>    
    $(function() {

    $("#myForm").validate({


    rules: {
            // simple rule, converted to {required:true}


            'productname[]': {
                required:true,
                minlength: 2,
                maxlength: 30,
            }

            }, //rules

    // pass options to ajaxForm 


    submitHandler: function(myForm) {
        var options = { 
            type: "POST",
            url: "form_submit2ajx.php",
            data: $("#myForm").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(msg){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").addClass(msg.statusgeneral);
                $("#formResponse").html(msg.statusgeneral);


            },
            error: function(){
                $("#formResponse").removeClass('success');
                $("#formResponse").addClass('error');
                $("#formResponse").html("There was an error submitting the form. Please try again.");
            } 
    }//var options  

    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options); 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit();
    return false;
    }       

    }); //validate()

}); //function
</script>
```

Comment: remove the comma after `maxlength: 30`

Comment: correctly noted, thnx. However, removing the comma does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed this

```
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
        $(this).ajaxSubmit();
```

instead try it this way

```
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options);
```

Comment: thnx. I already added the result handlers in the variable 'options'. Anyway, trying your suggestion did not solve the problem. The console log (monitoring 'msg.statusgeneral'does indicate an error in red but dissapears in less than a second. Before writing the handler within validate() I wrote a separate ajax handler - $("#myForm").submit(function() {$.ajax({ }) }) - which works fine. Is it possible to call that handler within the handler in validate()?

Comment: I believe you can but maybe try changing "this" to "#myForm" it may be out of scope

Comment: which or did you try both ?

Comment: why are you returning false ?

Comment: I changed "this" to "#myForm" as suggested. I also tried the suggested "$(this).ajaxSubmit(options);" Return false to prevent normal browser submit and page navigation (ref: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api).